# Oddify an even function and vice versa?

Tags: function-construction

I want to know how to construct a function in Mathematica which would produce even analog of odd function and vice versa in closed form?

The mathematical definitions are as follows:

$$\operatorname{odd}[f(x)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {n+1/2}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(2k)}(0)$$

$$\operatorname{even}[f(x)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {n-1/2}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(2k+1)}(0)$$

The operators `even` and `odd` are linear and inverse to each other if `even` is applied to an odd function and `odd` is applied to an even function.

For instance, the operators should give:

$$\operatorname{even}[x]=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
$$\operatorname{even}[\sinh x]=\cosh x$$
$$\operatorname{even}\left[-\frac 1\pi\psi\left(1-\frac x\pi\right)\right]=\csc^2 x - \frac1{x^2}$$

Some graphics of the pairs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Kuba I only can construct these operators in numerical form in Mathematica, I have no idea how to make such operator that would give results in closed form.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to (want to) use the infinite series form of even[] and odd[]? If not, this will get you the graphical parts of the even and odd extension very simply...

L = 1;
f[x_] = Sqrt[x];
feven[x_] = Piecewise[{{f[x], 0 < x < L}, {f[-x], -L < x < 0}}];
fodd[x_] = Piecewise[{{f[x], 0 < x < L}, {-f[-x], -L < x < 0}}];
GraphicsRow[{Plot[f[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}], 
 Plot[feven[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}], 
 Plot[fodd[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]

Comment: @JohnD No, I am interested in those operators I posted in the question. I am not interested in piecewise extensions. Among other properties these operators have a property that they asymoptotically approach each other as $x\to+\infty$ and their sum goes to zero as $x\to-\infty$. Also the value of the even function in $x=0$ is equal to the derivative of the odd function.

Comment: Maybe I've done something wrong but it doesn't seem to converge `Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{
    Sum[x^(
        2 n)/(2 n!) Sum[
         Binomial[n - 1/2, m] Sum[
           Binomial[m, k] (-1)^(m - k) D[#, {x, 2 k + 1}], {k, 0, 
            m}], {m, 0, r}], {n, 0, r}] &[x],
    x,
    Sqrt[1 + x^2]}],
  {x, -2, 2}],
 {{r, 1}, 1, 25, 2}]`

Comment: @Kuba for the first pair of functions it will diverge, one needs to modify the formula so it to work. But essentially the principle is the same.

Comment: @Kuba it also seems your formula has error. Why do u evaluate the derivative at x rather than 0?

Comment: @Anixx Ah, so I made a mistake, sorry, didn't pay attention. Feel free to fix it, I don't have time now.

Comment: @Kuba also it should be (2n)!, not 2 n!

Comment: @Kuba this works: f[x_]:=Sinh[x]
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{Sum[(x)^(2 n)/((2 n)!) Sum[Binomial[n-1/2,m] Sum[Binomial[m,k] (-1)^(m-k)Function[s,Evaluate[D[f[s],{s,2 k+1}]]][0],{k,0,m}],{m,0,r}],{n,0,r}],f[x]}],{x,-2,2},AspectRatio->Automatic],{{r,25},1,50,2}]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP, showing no effort of his own, is simply begging others to write code for him.